# How to select specific element in react.js

Tags: reactjs, element

I want to select specific element with className "material-icons-outlined" and add new class to that element

In javascript i would do it like this

```
document.querySelectorAll(".material-icons-outlined").forEach(icon => {
    icon.classList.add("notranslate");
})
```

But in react that doesn't work though, so how to do that in a react way?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is refs.
Take a look :)

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can still do that in React, just put those lines in `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".material-icons-outlined").forEach((icon) => {
      // check if already has the class
      if (!icon.classList.contains("notranslate"))
        icon.classList.add("notranslate");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout ref or useRef in reactjs It is your answer.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.yourRef = React.createRef()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="divR" ref={this.yourRef}>...</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```